# How to Write For Each Loop to Process Through String Array to Count Substrings

Tags: java, foreach

Was using a for loop to process through a String array and to test if the content of the cell matched with a substring, if so, count++.

The compiler is telling me that this can be written as a for-each loop.  I'm not very experienced using for-each loops, and the geeks for geeks articles are not helping.

Could someone kindly walk me through this simple conversion?

```
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        if(parts[i].contains(subString)){
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(count);
```

Comment: you can do something like this **parts.forEach(p -> {
         if(p.contains(subString))
          count++;
        });**

Comment: @ArunPrasat What is your definition of `parts` ?

Comment: parts I thought as an arraylist sorry it will be like **Arrays.stream(parts).forEach(p -> { if(p.contains(subString)) count++; });**

Comment: @ArunPrasat thanks for your time and help, mad respect.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for your time and help, mad respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `parts` is a String array, you can do

```
for (String p : parts) {
    if(p.contains(subString))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```